# В каком типе данных лучше хранить географические координаты?

Tags: mysql, координаты, геокодирование

Хватит ли точности double - или всё-таки в тексте хранить? Я вот не могу этого в документации уловить. Подскажите.

Comment: Целого (INT) вполне достаточно

Comment: посмотрите какая точность у double, посмотрите какой точности бывают координаты - сравните. Вот и все. И что вы собираетесь с этими координатами делать - просто хранить? Или потом еще и использовать. Если использовать, то как? Подойдет ли для этого строка или ее потом придется конвертировать в другой тип.

Comment: Я не могу найти допустимого числа цифр после запятой у double. Может, его в decimal лучше - и явно указать? Координаты планируется хранить и подставлять в ELASTIC SEARCH  для поиска по локации. Но нельзя исключить, что сами начнём вычислять что-то.

Comment: Почему не в DECIMAL? самое то... и знаков после запятой от пуза, и тип - точный.

Comment: Согласен. decimal

Comment: Вам нужно оттолкнуться от немного других вещей. Допустим вы захотите написать запрос, типа `SELECT * FROM points WHERE (long>127 AND long<128)  AND (lat>45 AND lat<46)`. Как обеспечить такому запросу хорошую производительность? Придётся использовать функциональность заложенную в MySQL для реализации таких запросов. Когда вы узнаете какая функциональность для этого заложена (если она вообще заложена, а если нет, то всё грустно), вы узнаете какие типы данных эта функциональность поддерживает. И тогда ваш вопрос отпадёт сам собой.

Comment: Хотя нельзя исключать, что всё это будет преждевременной оптимизацией для вашего проекта

Answer (score 0):

**decimal(11,8)** - Этого хватит для самых подробных координат, с которыми придётся работать.